# Origin of different brainwaves

Tags: neuroscience, eeg, neural-engineering

I'm creating a project in which I can measure brainwaves (more or less like EEG). Since I'm not a medical student im having a problem finding the origin or most prominent regions for measurements of alpha and beta waves. I have researched on the internet but can't find a definite solution. So can  someone please tell me the exact origin or the most prominent region (active region) of our brain where  the alpha and beta waves can be measured reliably??( Like ocipital region or frontal temporal etc)

Comment: This is probably not off-topic here but I personally think this is an excellent question for the [psychology & neuroscience SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). Also, the first search engine link I stumble on states that alpha waves mainly "originate from the occipital lobe during wakeful relaxation with closed eyes" and beta waves are "general over the whole cortex and occur during normal wakefulness". I think this checks out but I'm not entirely confident this answer is as satisfactory as one you could get from a cognitive neuroscientist.

Comment: If I ask the question now on nueroscience then it will be marked as  duplicate right??

Comment: It wouldn't. It's a completely separate stack exchange. Please try to search whether an answer already exists there. Also, put in a little effort using a search engine, I'm sure this information may exist already on online educational pages. If you are still lost, feel free to ask there!

Comment: @infottie Does this answer your question? https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/20075/why-do-brains-oscillate-within-specific-frequency-ranges/20086

Comment: No it doesn't..it doesn't say which wave is most prominent in which part of the Brain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha and beta brainwaves are just two of several arbitrary, named frequency ranges for a brain-wide phenomenon. See [Types of Brain waves](https://brainworksneurotherapy.com/what-are-brainwaves). These so-called brainwaves are big electrical events that sweep across the entire brain.

My recommendation for electrode placement is based on my engineering experience. Pick any location on the scalp. You could start with the temples. Take your measurements. Then move the electrodes to a different location and repeat the measurement. Continue this experimentation until you discover by observation which location yields the best results. When you have finished with the experiment, you can post your experimental results on SE Biology and answer your own question.

I suspect that electrode type and method of contact (dry versus conductive gel) will be more significant than actual placement on the head.